# gRPC networking on MacOs to Kubernetes running Istio

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, docker-for-mac

I am having problems connecting **gRPC** to **Istio** via **Kuberneres** running **Docker-For-Desktop** on **MacOs**.

Update: This also do not(or is the same problem) work on Google Kubernetes Engine.

Update: If you have this gRPC(any gRPC sample) setup working on GKE, please let me know!

Update: This works straight out of the box with Ambassador:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: auth-service-grpc
  name: auth-service-grpc
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    sidecar.istio.io/inject: false
    getambassador.io/config: |
      ---
      apiVersion: ambassador/v0
      kind: Mapping
      name: grpc_mapping
      grpc: true
      prefix: /main.Greeter/
      rewrite: /main.Greeter/
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    name: grpc-greet
    targetPort: grpc-auth
  selector:
    app: auth-deployment-grpc
```

grpc_cli ls localhost:3000 -l

```
D0827 12:45:51.753655000 140736110936960 ev_posix.cc:142]              Using polling engine: poll
D0827 12:45:51.756976000 140736110936960 dns_resolver.cc:331]          Using native dns resolver
I0827 12:45:51.763898000 140736110936960 subchannel.cc:608]            New connected subchannel at 0x7f83ebd05ea0 for subchannel 0x7f83ebd045b0
filename: grpc_reflection_v1alpha/reflection.proto
package: grpc.reflection.v1alpha;
service ServerReflection {
  rpc ServerReflectionInfo(stream grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflectionRequest) returns (stream grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflectionResponse) {}
}

filename: auth.proto
package: pb;
service Auth {
  rpc TheMethod(pb.TheRequest) returns (pb.TheReply) {}
}
```

But not with Istio?

For starters: `grpc_cli ls localhost:3000 -l` shows me:

```
export GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG
grpc_cli ls localhost:3000 -l                                            
D0826 14:42:35.175041000 140736110936960 ev_posix.cc:142]              Using polling engine: poll
D0826 14:42:35.176359000 140736110936960 dns_resolver.cc:331]          Using native dns resolver
I0826 14:42:35.180535000 140736110936960 subchannel.cc:646]            Connect failed: {"created":"@1535287355.180495000","description":"Failed to connect to remote host: OS Error","errno":61,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_client_posix.cc","file_line":201,"os_error":"Connection refused","syscall":"connect","target_address":"ipv6:[::1]:3000"}
I0826 14:42:35.180675000 140736110936960 subchannel.cc:646]            Connect failed: {"created":"@1535287355.180647000","description":"Failed to connect to remote host: OS Error","errno":61,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_client_posix.cc","file_line":201,"os_error":"Connection refused","syscall":"connect","target_address":"ipv4:127.0.0.1:3000"}
I0826 14:42:35.180691000 140736110936960 subchannel.cc:470]            Subchannel 0x7fb149503470: Retry in 1000 milliseconds
Received an error when querying services endpoint.
I0826 14:42:35.180827000 140736110936960 proto_reflection_descriptor_database.cc:51] ServerReflectionInfo rpc failed. Error code: 14, details: Connect Failed
```

grpc_cli ls localhost:8060 -l:

```
D0827 12:13:36.558654000 140736110936960 ev_posix.cc:142]              Using polling engine: poll
D0827 12:13:36.559903000 140736110936960 dns_resolver.cc:331]          Using native dns resolver
I0827 12:13:36.565146000 140736110936960 subchannel.cc:608]            New connected subchannel at 0x7fa28c5068c0 for subchannel 0x7fa28c504eb0
D0827 12:13:36.567485000 140736110936960 dns_resolver.cc:247]          In cooldown from last resolution (from 7 ms ago). Will resolve again in 993 ms
Received an error when querying services endpoint.
I0827 12:13:36.568479000 140736110936960 proto_reflection_descriptor_database.cc:51] ServerReflectionInfo rpc failed. Error code: 14, details: Socket closed
```

Port `3000` is not open, and If I do a port scan on `127.0.0.1` I get this:

```
Port Scanning host: 127.0.0.1

     Open TCP Port:     80          http
     Open TCP Port:     443         https
     Open TCP Port:     631         ipp
     Open TCP Port:     6443        sun-sr-https
     Open TCP Port:     8060
     Open TCP Port:     15011
     Open TCP Port:     15030
     Open TCP Port:     15031
     Open TCP Port:     31400
     Open TCP Port:     65190
Port Scan has completed…
```

Note, I have turned off Firewalls on the MacOs.

istio-system:

```
svc/istio-ingressgateway       LoadBalancer   10.105.30.214    localhost     80:31380/TCP,443:31390/TCP,31400:31400/TCP,15011:31361/TCP,8060:30030/TCP,15030:32411/TCP,3000:31399/TCP
```

Just to show that the beneath gateway settings, is coming through with helm update of it values.

And `kubectl cluster-info` shows this:

```
kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://localhost:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://localhost:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```

I have in installed Istio with Helm and I have added `ports` to Istio helm installation `values.yaml`

```
  gateways:
    enabled: true

    istio-ingressgateway:
      enabled: true
      labels:
        app: istio-ingressgateway
        istio: ingressgateway
      replicaCount: 1
      autoscaleMin: 1
      autoscaleMax: 5
      resources: {}
        # limits:
        #  cpu: 100m
        #  memory: 128Mi
        #requests:
        #  cpu: 1800m
        #  memory: 256Mi

      loadBalancerIP: ""
      serviceAnnotations: {}
      type: LoadBalancer #change to NodePort, ClusterIP or LoadBalancer if need be

      ports:
        ## You can add custom gateway ports
      - port: 80
        targetPort: 80
        name: http
        nodePort: 31380
      - port: 443
        name: https
        nodePort: 31390
      - port: 31400
        name: tcp
        nodePort: 31400
      # Pilot and Citadel MTLS ports are enabled in gateway - but will only redirect
      # to pilot/citadel if global.meshExpansion settings are enabled.
      - port: 15011
        targetPort: 15011
        name: tcp-pilot-grpc-tls
      - port: 8060
        targetPort: 8060
        name: tcp-citadel-grpc-tls
      # Telemetry-related ports are enabled in gateway - but will only redirect if
      # the gateway configration for the various components are enabled.
      - port: 15030
        targetPort: 15030
        name: http2-prometheus
      - port: 15031
        targetPort: 15031
        name: http2-grafana
  # awear-grpc
        name: grpc
        nodePort: 31399
        port: 3000
        targetPort: 3000
```

Also tried to create a custom `kind: Gateway`:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
  labels:
    awear: my-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: istio-ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 3000
      name: grpc-my
      protocol: GRPC
    hosts:
    - "my-service-grpc.default.svc.cluster.local"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `grpc_cli ls localhost:8060 -l` And post the answer here.

Comment: Thanks Nick - I Just updated with grpc_cli ls localhost:8060 -l

Comment: As you see you have connection and all is work fine.

Comment: Not really, but I will take you word for it :-) So where do you think it goes wrong if I want to use gRPC via port 3000?

Comment: In other words, how would you debug this?

Comment: Can you please shorten your problem? It's really difficult to read through and you're using both Istio and Ambassador and MacOS for some reason. Please just show one case that it works and one it doesn't.